# Local maximum for small ints in a text file

Tags: shell, scripting

Given a text file like:

```
a 3
a 1
b 4
a 2
b 1
```

I would like to return:

```
a 3
b 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$2 > a[$1]{a[$1]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
a 3
b 4
```